# Dynamic attributes nesting within composite components

Tags: jsf, el, composite-component, dynamic-attributes

I am struggling with nesting dynamic JSF attributes within composite components.

Let us imagine following structure on client side:

```
class BackingBean{
    Animal animal;
}

class Animal {
    Type type;
}

class Type{
    String name;
}
```

On the view side I can reach to the nested fields using `.` character:

`#{backingBean.animal.type.name}`

In that case, everything works like a charm. Problem emerges when I want to rewerite it into `composite component` and represent nested `fields` as a separate `attributes`:

```
<cc:interface>  
    <cc:attribute name="mainAttribute"/>
    <cc:attribute name="nestedAttribute"/>
    <cc:attribute name="valuesProviderService"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.valuesProviderService.findAnimals}" 
    var="animal" itemValue="#{animal}" itemLabel="#{$HERE_IS_NESTING$}" />
</cc:implementation>
```

I tried a variety of approaches, but I guess my current knowledge is not enough to solve it.

I tried to use nesting with `[` character like:

`itemLabel="#{animal[cc.attrs.mainAttribute[cc.attrs.nestedAttribute]]}"`

also tried with `c:set`

```
<c:set var="main" value="#{cc.attrs.mainAttribute}" />
<c:set var="nested" value="#{cc.attrs.nestedAttribute}" />
```

and then use it `itemLabel="#{animal.main.nested}"`

I hope you know what I want to achieve. Can you help me out a bit here?

Comment: can you post what error are you getting when you use only `itemLabel="#{animal.main.nested}"` on your composite implementation

Comment: @DavidFlorez It does not produce any error. Problem emerges when I use composite component, which would be generic, attributes cannot be used in the same way.